# WebDriverWait timeout not being triggered until wait.until condition returns true

Tags: selenium

I have a Selenium script that uploads several zip files.  These zip files vary in size and duration for uploading, and the resulting web page can either display an error, success or simply continue to wait until the upload is complete.

I'm attempting to test for either of the first two conditions to be true using an explicit wait.  The script does pause and wait for one or the other conditions to be true, but it does not trigger a timeout exception until after the moveOn() function is completed.  For instance, it may take 5 minutes to upload the zip and my function will wait that entire time, but afterwards it raises an error that the timeout exceeded 30 seconds.  I was expecting the timeout to trigger an error inside of the moveOn() function so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I was using http://www.bizalgo.com/2012/01/14/timing-races-selenium-2-implicit-waits-explicit-waits/ as the basis for what I was attempting to do.

The calling code:

```
try{
... 
    String click = "jq(\"a[title='Import']\").click();";
    js.executeScript(click);
    moveOn();
...   
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error in importing zip " + courseName + ".  Exception:" + e);
}
```

My explicitWait routine:

```
  private void moveOn()
            {
             WebDriverWait wdw = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
             ExpectedCondition<Boolean> condition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() 
             {
                 @Override
                 public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) 
                 {
                    Boolean error = false;
                    Boolean success = false;
                    //Look for error
                    WebElement result1 = d.findElement(By.className("wdkErrorGoBack"));
                          if( "Error".equals(result1.getText()))
                                  {
                                  error = true;
                                  }
                    //Look for success
                    WebElement result2 = d.findElement(By.className("sbMainPageInstructions"));
                          if( "The content has been imported successfully.".equals(result2.getText()))
                                  {
                                  success = true;
                                  } 
                  //Return true if either are true
                  return (error || success);
                 }
               };
           //Wait until either condition is met or timeout expires
           wdw.until(condition); 
            }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Follow up:**
I've switched to executeAsyncScript, but I still cannot seem to get the script to timeout in the time specified.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
String ex = "cb = arguments[ arguments.length - 1 ];\n"  +
          "(function(){jq(\"a[title='Import']\").click();}());\n" +
          "str=jq(this).find('.wdkErrorGoBack,.sbMainPageInstructions').eq(0).text();\n"+
           "cb(str);";
System.out.println(ex);
Object response = js.executeAsyncScript(ex);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are seeing that behavior because `js.executeScript` is a blocking call much like the `driver.get` call. The fact that the code waits for 5 minutes per your example is an indication of that. So your wait is being triggered after the js execution is complete.

As for timeout error being triggered within the `moveOn()` function, not quite sure I understand what you mean by that. By design the error will be triggered after the wait for 30 seconds is complete so it will throw an error after the function is complete.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll have to do some more research on the blocking aspects of js.executeScript.  js.executeScript is just clicking on a button that starts the upload process via HTML POST.  The moveOn() function is looking for two possible server responses.  Maybe I should put the js.executeScript inside the moveOn() function???  RE: the timeout.  With a 30 second timeout in my WebDriverWait instance, it should raise an error 30.01 seconds into the routine if not complete, right?  However, the entire function completes, file uploads, html is drawn and then the timeout error is raised.

Comment: Yes, the timeout exception should be thrown after 30 seconds of waiting on the condition. It really depends on how your JS logic is setup for the POST method. One thing you could try is execute the script in async which will probably give you control immediately. But the question really is what exactly are you trying to test? Upload a big file and make sure the timeout error happens while the upload is still going because the appropriate status message is not present?

Comment: "Upload a big file and make sure the timeout error happens while the upload is still going because the appropriate status message is not present? "  Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to trigger.  If the upload never completes for some reason, I don't want to have the script just stay stuck here and not move on to the next file to upload.

Comment: As mentioned before, try using `js.executeAsyncScript` to see if that helps. It should return the control immediately to the moveOn function and the timeout will trigger mid-upload.

Comment: Thank you.  I am trying it and it seems to do what I need it to do.  Thank you for the help.